# Trigger on User when ContactID changes then update Contact.User__c

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id

Want to write before an update Trigger, when User.ContactID changes from Null to not null or not null to another null then update the contact.User__C to user.id.

I am not understanding how can I update the Contact.User__C to User.id, Any help would be appreciated.

```
trigger TriggerContactIDChange on User (before update) {
    List<ID> UserID = new List<ID>();

    for (User newUser : Trigger.new) { 
        UserID.add(newUser.ID);
    }

    List<Contact> myContacts = [SELECT Id, User__c FROM contact WHERE Id IN :UserID];

    for (Contact currentContact : myContacts) {
        currentContact.User__C = currentContact.Id;
    } 
}
```

Comment: As a side note, a `before update` trigger isn't really appropriate here because you're not updating any fields on the records in `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap` (the benefit of `before` triggers is that you can adjust fields on records in `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap` and have them saved to the record(s) without the need for DML). Generally speaking, an `after update` trigger would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly do this, because this will result in a MIXED_DML_ERROR. It's not possible to update a user and a contact in the same transaction. At minimum, you'll need to defer to a future/queueable method.

```
public class Utils {
  @future public static void updateContacts(Id[] userIds, Id[] contactIds) {
    Contact[] records = new Contact[0];
    while(!userIds.isEmpty()) {
      records.add(new Contact(Id=contactIds.remove(0), User__c=userIds.remove(0)));
    }
    update records;
  }
}
```

---

```
trigger TriggerContactIDChange on User (after insert, after update) {
  Id[] userIds = new Id[0], contactIds = new Id[0];
  for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.old[index].ContactId != Trigger.new[index].ContactId) {
      if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.old[index].ContactId != null) {
        userIds.add(Trigger.old[index].Id);
        contactIds.add(Trigger.old[index].ContactId);
      }
      if(Trigger.new[index].ContactId != null) {
        userIds.add(Trigger.new[index].Id);
        contactIds.add(Trigger.new[index].ContactId);
      }
    }
  }
  if(!userIds.isEmpty()) {
    Utils.updateContacts(userIds, contactIds);
  }
}
```

I have not tested this, either, so you may need to modify this further, but it is the minimum amount of effort you'll need to put forth to make this work.

Comment: just curious -- is there a reason you did the `while(!userIds.isEmpty())` rather than `for (Integer i = 0; i < userIds.size(); i++)` pattern ?

Comment: Thanks much, it saved my ass!!, will be writing my code here so that could improve me code quality and do follow the best practices. @sfdcfoX

Comment: @cropredy No particular reason, actually. Either would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you help me figure out this please?

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225242/you-do-not-have-the-necessary-permissions-to-disable-this-portal-user#225242